# validate saml token in web api

Tags: c#, token, saml

I have a SAML Token that I wanted to validate whether is valid or invalid.  The SAML Token is generated from ADFS with ActiveDirectory attributes as Claim.  Is there a standard way to decode and validate the token?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.saml2securitytokenhandler.validatetoken(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

If the token you have is in XML form, there is a `ReadToken()` method you can use to parse it.

Comment: I configured in web.config file to have <audienceUris>, issuerNameRegistry, trustedIssuers, securityTokenHandlers, federatedAuthentication
<serviceCertificate>
        <certificateReference x509FindType="FindByIssuerDistinguishedName" findValue

<microsoft.identityModel>

But when 401 is encountered, it doesnt redirect to the login page.  I thought the authentication of the token will be handled by the microsoft.identityModel in web.config file? I'm using .NET framework 4.5.

Comment: You should use the `<system.identityModel>` section if you are using .NET 4.5. `<microsoft.identityModel>` is the legacy WIF namespace. I assumed you already had the token - if you want full SAML Web SSO support you need a Service Provider module such as [Kentor.AuthServices](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices).

Comment: I downgraded .NET framework to 4.0 instead and is working using microsoft.identityModel